# RS485 star topology

Tags: rs485

I have to create a system based on a series of remote sensors that must communicate with a central node. The sensors are all connected with an RS485 bus. Theoretically I should create a classic online BUS, like this:
[image]

The problem is that for installation requirements, all the cables to the sensors must all start from the central node; therefore, a star network would be created.

The question is: can an RS485 bus work with a star topology? Are there any tricks that can make it work with a star topology?

Comment: What are your requirements concerning the distances between the center and the end of the arms, the baudrate, and the complexity of the master?

Comment: Why do they have to be common bus, why can't they be muxed on independent transceivers for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick search found [Is Star Topology of MODBUS-RS485 Possible?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/402084/is-star-topology-of-modbus-rs485-possible/1424365#1424365) on a TI forum. The accepted answer from TI employee Christian Klickow contains:

> In general **such a star topology can not be realized** with a "simple" RS-485. The reflections that would be caused by these long stubs (connections between your main bus and the slave nodes) make a reliable data transmission impossible. If you would terminate every single node you would end up with 7 times 120 Ohms (120 Ohm twisted pair assumed) in parallel, which results in a 17.14 Ohms load for the differential driver.

Some other suggestions in the referenced thread include using a separate RS485 transceiver in the master device for each slave port.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, it all comes down to how far and how fast, and how long the stubs are.  but the simplest solution just uses more wire.

**Have you considered wiring which is Electrically a Bus and Physically a Star?**

Obviously it adds cable (or cores), and connector pins, but perhaps addresses your problem.

[image]

Comment: I had also thought about this solution, but the distances are not short, we are also talking about sensors at 80/100 meters; therefore, going there and back would lengthen the route a lot.

Comment: RS-485 can go up to 1000 m. Slowing the bitrate will dramaticaly improve the possibilities. If the total of all cables is too long, then you will have to use more than one transciever.

Comment: @FedericoMassimi It's best to put speed/distance/quantity in the question.  Obviously this solution doubles the cabling length.  How long is "not short"?  What is the bit rate?  How many nodes do you have?

Answer (score 6):

There are many application notes about this. It is not recommended and under specific conditions it can be made to work with tricks but we don't know if your system can work.

If the bit rate is "slow" and slew rate is "slow" in comparison to cable length and how long reflections are allowed to bounce back and forth in the system, it might be possible. The application notes have some guidelines.

Best thing to do is to make the bus electrically linear while routing the cables in a star fashion, so each cable from center to device loops the data back to center from where it goes to next device.

Another option is to have a separate RS-485 bus to each sensor to make the links point to point.

Comment: I don't have enough UART to have an RS485 bus for each sensor, but I could use a single UART and put an RS485 buffer (for example this one: MAX33045EASA+) for each sensor. Then using the two enable to enable only one buffer at a time, could that be a solution?

If I read correctly from the datasheet, when it is not enabled the receiver is in high impedance on the MCU side, so I should have no problems having multiple drivers on the same pin as the UART of my MCU. Right?

Comment: @FedericoMassimi That is possible if the sensors never initiate communication. But categorigally saying that star topology is not possible is simply wrong, but it will also be difficult to get iy working.

Comment: The sensors send data only when requested by the master, they never send anything of their own free will.